# Change the permissions of the files generated by Wordpress on the server

Tags: php, wordpress, file, permissions, file-permissions

I always upload my Wordpress files on the server so the "owner" is my username and I can change the permission to, let's say, 770. But when I install a plugin, the owner becomes "www-data" and the permission is `rw-r-xr--`. However, I need to modify some files. Can I do something in the Wordpress config to change the generated file's default permissions? I'm not the server's root. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Its simple please see

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Override_of_default_file_permissions

It is as below::

Override of default file permissions
The FS_CHMOD_DIR and FS_CHMOD_FILE define statements allow override of default file permissions. These two variables were developed in response to the problem of the core update function failing with hosts (e.g. some Italian hosts) running under suexec. If a host uses restrictive file permissions (e.g. 400) for all user files, and refuses to access files which have group or world permissions set, these definitions could solve the problem. Note that the '0755' is an octal value. Octal values must be prefixed with a 0 and are not delineated with single quotes (').

```
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0755 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0644 & ~ umask() ) );
```

Example to provide setgid:

```
define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 02755 & ~umask() ) );
```

If you want to change file permissions see

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

EDIT:

Put these after putting any of the above code:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *          # Let apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
```

Comment: I added `define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0777 & ~ umask() ) ); define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0777 & ~ umask() ) );` to `wp-config.php` but after installing a plugin, www-data is still the owner of the newly created files and the permission is not 0777 but `rw-r--r--` (I know, that's horrible but I only did it for testing purposes). Thank you.

Comment: @user4668176 edited please see it add the following and give me the result and also can you give the name of the plugin you are using please

Comment: Thanks but I added the edit after the above code and when I went to the site for initial configuration, the page was blank.

Comment: And also what are the plugins you are using

Comment: Install the plugin manually may also do good @user4668176 and also check my other comments

Comment: But that URL I gave you is just a fresh install of Wordpress, no Jomres plugin yet. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sir Abhishek. If ever you're reading this, I'll take down the site first. I need to return to my tasks. I'll let you know if the url is up and running again, if you still have to. Thank you.

Comment: `define( 'FS_CHMOD_DIR', ( 0755 & ~ umask() ) );
define( 'FS_CHMOD_FILE', ( 0644 & ~ umask() ) );`          Add these lines after your fresh install to the bottom on the config.php and when you install a plugin do it again and try to install plugins manually so that you are the one who can chose whether or not to replace those lines and remember to put the lines of code on the bottom of the wp-config.php after you install all your plugins so that they can override the plugin's code. I hope you understand please accept as the best answer if this helps @user4668176

Comment: And also be sure to replace 0755 and 644 with your respective file permission codes full list available here : http://www.askapache.com/security/chmod-stat.html#Permission_0000_0777 and put a zero in front of the codes that you would get by following the link. I hope this solves the problem please accept it as the best answer if it solves the problem and for more just comment.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct file permissions for Wordpress:

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *          # Let apache be owner
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  # Change directory permissions rwxr-xr-x
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;  # Change file permissions rw-r--r--
```

Depending on your server configuration you may put your `wp-content` on `775`. This permission will allow your group to write in this folder. Why add group permissions? Because in wordpress, you can have **two users working on files**, the `www-data` user (who executes the website) and the `ftp user` (who downloads **plugins and updates** from the webplatform wordpress). You can put your `wp-content` on `755` but you have to make `www-data` the **owner** of this folder and do your updates manually via FTP.

Learn more about [wordpress File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)

Comment: Thanks but I put `wp-content` to `755` and tried to make `www-data` the owner but it said "Permission denied".