# WordPress statement from wp-config.php

Tags: wordpress, bash

I'm having trouble understanding what this statement does:

define('FS_CHMOD_DIR', (0775 & ~ umask()));

This article describes FS_CHMOD_DIR -- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253274/use-of-undefined-constant-fs-chmod-dir-assumed-fs-chmod-dir

However, I'm confused by:
0775 & ~ umask()

Could you help me make sense of this?

Comment: Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30194811/change-the-permissions-of-the-files-generated-by-wordpress-on-the-server